# I am getting a null pointer exception on executing database Helper

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting a null pointer exception on listviewholder.cart

below on excuting database helper :-

```
package com.emagic.newproject.adpaters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.emagic.newproject.ItemsActivity;
import com.emagic.newproject.NewProject;
import com.emagic.newproject.R;
import com.emagic.newproject.model.Items;
import com.emagic.newproject.model.ItemsListRowViewHolder;
import com.emagic.newproject.util.SQLiteHelper;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mkodekar on 12/7/2015.
 */
public class ItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsListRowViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    public List<Items> itemsList;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = NewProject.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private int focusedItem = 0;

    SQLiteHelper db;
    ItemsActivity itemsActivity = new ItemsActivity();
    private static final int TEXT_ID = 0;

    int total , price, quan;

    String value,date, productName, email, rate, quantity, amount;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, List<Items> itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public ItemsListRowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_item, null);
        ItemsListRowViewHolder holder = new ItemsListRowViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemsListRowViewHolder listRowViewHolder, final int position) {
        Items itemsListItems = itemsList.get(position);
        listRowViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);

        listRowViewHolder.getLayoutPosition();

        imageLoader = NewProject.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        listRowViewHolder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(itemsListItems.getImage(), imageLoader);
        listRowViewHolder.thumbnail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        listRowViewHolder.name.setText(itemsListItems.getName());
        setAnimation(listRowViewHolder.itemView, focusedItem);

        listRowViewHolder.productPrice.setText(itemsListItems.getPrice());
        listRowViewHolder.description.setText(itemsListItems.getDescription());

        listRowViewHolder.quantity.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        listRowViewHolder.quantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setTitle("Quantity");
                builder.setMessage("Add the amount of pieces to be required");
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                final EditText input = new EditText(mContext);
                input.setId(TEXT_ID);
                input.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                input.setSingleLine();
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                builder.setView(input);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        value = input.getText().toString();
                        listRowViewHolder.quantity.setText(value);

                        Log.d(ItemsActivity.TAG, "Value: " + value);
                        try {
                            // ** here you can perform ur calculations
                            price = Integer.parseInt(listRowViewHolder.productPrice.getText().toString());
                            quan = Integer.parseInt(listRowViewHolder.quantity.getText().toString());
                            total = price * quan;

                            amount = String.valueOf(total);
                            listRowViewHolder.totalAmount.setText(amount);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        return;
                    }


                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });

        listRowViewHolder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String count = listRowViewHolder.quantity.getText().toString();
                int cnt = Integer.parseInt(count);
                cnt++;
                listRowViewHolder.quantity.setText("" + cnt);

                try {
                    // ** here you can perform ur calculations
                    price = Integer.parseInt(listRowViewHolder.productPrice.getText().toString());
                    quan = Integer.parseInt(listRowViewHolder.quantity.getText().toString());
                    total = price * quan;

                    amount = String.valueOf(total);
                    listRowViewHolder.totalAmount.setText(amount);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

        listRowViewHolder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String count = listRowViewHolder.quantity.getText().toString();
                int cnt = Integer.parseInt(count);

                if (cnt == 0) {

                    listRowViewHolder.quantity.setText("0");


                } else {

                    cnt--;
                    listRowViewHolder.quantity.setText("" + cnt);

                }

                try {
                    // ** here you can perform ur calculations
                    price = Integer.parseInt(listRowViewHolder.productPrice.getText().toString());
                    quan = Integer.parseInt(listRowViewHolder.quantity.getText().toString());
                    total = price * quan;

                    amount = String.valueOf(total);
                    listRowViewHolder.totalAmount.setText(amount);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        listRowViewHolder.cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ItemsActivity itemsActivity = new ItemsActivity();
                int objectLength = itemsActivity.object;
                int position;

                for(position = 0; position <= objectLength; position++) {
                    listRowViewHolder.quantity.setText(value);
                    quantity = String.valueOf(value);
                    productName = listRowViewHolder.name.getText().toString();
                    rate = listRowViewHolder.productPrice.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("Email", 0);
                email = mPrefs.getString("SessionEmail", "");

                Date d = new Date();
                CharSequence dateChar = DateFormat.format("d-MM-yyyy ", d.getTime());
                date = String.valueOf(dateChar);

                amount = String.valueOf(total);

                db.createOrder(date , productName, email, rate, quantity, amount); //problemn is here.
                Toast.makeText(mContext, date + "" + productName+ " " + email + " " + rate + " " + quantity + " " + amount  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

public void clearAdapter() {
    itemsList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && position >= focusedItem) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        focusedItem = position;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && position >= focusedItem) {
        focusedItem = position;
    }
}
```

this is  the sqlite helper

```
package com.emagic.newproject.util;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
    private static final String TABLE_ORDER = "order";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "confirmPassword";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobileNumber";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String ORDER_ID = "order_id";
    private static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "productName";
    private static final String QUANTITY  = "quantity";
    private static final String RATE = "rate";
    private static final String AMOUNT = "amount";
    private static final String ORDER_DATE = "date";

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);


        String CREATE_ORDER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL +" TEXT,"
                + QUANTITY + "TEXT," + RATE + " TEXT," + AMOUNT + " TEXT," + ORDER_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ORDER_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_ORDER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String confirmPassword, String mobileNumber, String address) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, confirmPassword); // Email
        values.put(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, mobileNumber); // Created At
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("confirmPassword", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("mobileNumber", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("address", cursor.getString(5));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     */
    public void deleteUsers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
    }

    public void createOrder(String date, String productName, String email, String rate, String quantity, String amount) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(ORDER_DATE, date);
        values.put(PRODUCT_NAME, productName); // Email
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(RATE, rate); // Created At
        values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
        values.put(AMOUNT, amount);

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_ORDER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting order data from database
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getOrderDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> order = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ORDER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            order.put("date", cursor.getString(1));
            order.put("productName", cursor.getString(2));
            order.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            order.put("rate", cursor.getString(4));
            order.put("quantity", cursor.getString(5));
            order.put("amount", cursor.getString(6));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching order from Sqlite: " + order.toString());

        return order;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     */
    public void deleteOrder() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_ORDER, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all order info from sqlite");
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Porblem is i am sending an onclick even to save data in database from and adapter

problem ius mentioned in above post.

Comment: You're not initializing `db` anywhere. Also, you can't instantiate an Activity with `new` and have it work properly.

Comment: @MikeM. If you see i have initialized and the activity thing was just like thay its not used if you see.

Comment: 1) Please indicate the line in which you initialize `db` in `ItemListAdapter`, 'cause I can't find it. 2) I didn't say the Activity instantiation was causing your current problem. I was just advising you that you shouldn't do that. Also, you are using it. You're getting `objectLength`'s value from it.

Comment: Okay can you tell what to do there and i know now i get i have seriously initialized it but declared sqlitehelper's object.